# How to create 3D show and hide animations with velocity js

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, show-hide, velocity.js

**SCENARIO**

I want to hide all elements, then show one one specific element after that, from the set which had just been hidden. This has to happen in 3D.

**PROBLEM**

After hiding, only the last element works, and I don't get any errors whatsoever.

The following works, when I use "hide()";

```
$(document).on('click', '.navigation_but', function(){
        var nav = $(this).attr('data-nav');
        $(".article_sd").hide();
            $('.'+nav+'').velocity("transition.flipXIn");
    });
```

But this doesn't work, I don't know what im doing wrong.

```
$(document).on('click', '.navigation_but', function(){
            var nav = $(this).attr('data-nav');
            $(".article_sd").velocity("transition.flipXOut");
                $('.'+nav+'').velocity("transition.flipXIn");
        });
```

Markup is as follows.

**HTML**

---

```
<header>
<nav class="navigation_but" data-nav="article_sd_first">First</nav>
<nav class="navigation_but" data-nav="article_sd_second">Second</nav>
<nav class="navigation_but" data-nav="article_sd_third">Third</nav>
<nav class="navigation_but" data-nav="article_sd_fourth">Fourth</nav>
</header>
<section>
<article class="article_sd article_sd_first" style="background-color:rgba(0,85,0,1)"></article>
<article class="article_sd article_sd_second" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,153,1)"></article>
<article class="article_sd article_sd_third" style="background-color: rgba(153,102,204,1)"></article>
<article class="article_sd article_sd_fourth" style="background-color: rgba(51,51,102,1)"></article>
</section>
```

And some CSS

---

```
<style>
    .article_sd { height:100px;}
    </style>
```

or if possible put this fancy effects in place as seen from this demo;

https://codyhouse.co/demo/page-scroll-effects/opacity.html

```
$.Velocity
    .RegisterEffect("rotation", {
        defaultDuration: 1,
        calls: [ 
            [ { opacity: '0', rotateX: '90', translateY: '-100%'}, 1]
        ]
    });

$.Velocity
.RegisterEffect("rotation.scroll", {
    defaultDuration: 1,
    calls: [ 
        [ { opacity: '0', rotateX: '90', translateY: '0'}, 1]
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in here

```
$(document).on('click', '.navigation_but', function(){
        var nav = $(this).attr('data-nav');
        $(".article_sd").velocity("transition.flipXOut");
            $('.'+nav+'').velocity("transition.flipXIn");
    });
```

variable `nav` element is still animating when second velocity function is called. We don't want that to be so.

There is two at least two options you could try i think.

1) Stop earlier animation before starting new one. `$('.'+nav+'').velocity('stop').velocity("transition.flipXIn");`

2) Animate second animation AFTER first one using velocity/jquery style callback.

```
$(".article_sd").velocity("transition.flipXOut", function () {
  $('.' + nav).velocity('transition.flipXIn');
});
```

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: There's progress. The first one appears and disappears. The second one does the animation, but there's blank space between the two animations, if the background is white, there's a white long space before the second animation kicks in.

Comment: Do you want to animate 'nav' out at all? you could exclude it from first animation with :not() selector. https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

like $('.article_sd:not(.' + nav + ')').velocity(...

Comment: Please see my edit. I added a live demo link, the "Opacity Effect", is one of the ones I'd love to achieve on this.